# Large amounts of sensor data stored in mongodb or hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

My application deals with a large amounts of real time sensor data. The data can be used for big data analysis, which hadoop is of course the best choice to work on. But now I am just thinking whether I should firstly put the data into mongodb, and through the mongodb to hadoop interface to do the big data thing. Is mongodb needed since both of them can store the data and map reduce (hadoop is more advanced)?

May anyone help me to analyze the differences between hadoop and mongodb?
Should I combine them, or just keep hadoop only in this sensor based application architecture?

Comment: For the n-th time: Hadoop is no damn database.

Comment: @user824624: There is a very good, quite valid question in here.  I just think you didn't ask it in the correct form.  I strongly suggest you ask a new question along the lines of: "How can I use mongoDB and hadoop to store and process time series data?"

Comment: Hadoop is not a database engine; you cannot replace a database engine (such as MongoDb) with something that is not a database engine.

Comment: Mongodb is more practical for transnational data , storing data and it depends on many factors to use it for this reason . However Hadoop is used to solve Big Data issues , Hadoop can store , process and analyse big data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop is not a database - it's a data analysis framework.

But it needs to get its data from somewhere. MongoDB is one possible solution for storing your data for analysis by Hadoop. But whether it's a good or a bad solution depends on a lot of factors which you didn't mention in your question. Mostly how your data is structured and if you expect the structure to change in the future.